# what is need of connection open and close of execution in query in winform?

Tags: mysql, winforms

In my form, there are a lot of combo boxes. I want to load different table data to combo box. I am trying to do that, but code is very slow because of the connection open and close codings.

When I run two command in without close connection and open it throws an exception.

> There is already an open DataReader associated with this Connection which must be closed first.

How can I remove this open and close in my program? Here is my code:

```
string MyConString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["College_Management_System.Properties.Settings.cmsConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection(MyConString);
MySqlCommand command = connection.CreateCommand();
MySqlDataReader Reader;
command.CommandText = "select name from course_master";
connection.Open();
Reader = command.ExecuteReader();
while (Reader.Read())
{
    cmbo_course.Items.Add(Reader[0].ToString());
}

command.CommandText = "select name from country_master";
Reader = command.ExecuteReader();
while (Reader.Read())
{
    cmbo_perCountry.Items.Add(Reader[0].ToString());
    cmbo_country.Items.Add(Reader[0].ToString());
}
connection.Close();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try by using this

```
Reader = command.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection());
```